# Pagination with Ionic 3 Firestore and Observables

Tags: scroll, pagination, ionic3, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to figure out how to do pagination for the following scenario. Please let me know if there is an easier way and I am complicating it. Its using Ionic 3 and firestore.

show.html

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of observable | async">
{{item.value}}
</ion-row>

<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

show.ts

```
observable: Observable<any[]>;

this.observable = this.provider.getData();  //in the corstructor method
```

provider.ts

```
getData(){
return this.afs.collection('data').limit(10).snapshotChanges().map(a=>{
        return a.map(x=> {
          return {
            value: x.payload.doc.data(),
          };
        });
      });
  }
```

So, I am calling a method from provider.ts to get the collection list as observable in my show.ts file. The observable is getting displayed in the show.html with `async` pipe

In order to do a pagination for firestore I have to use `startAt(dataSnap)` or `startAfter(dataSnap)`. To use these methods I need the last data snapshot of the collection. How can I get the last item from an observable? 
Any idea how to proceed with this approach.